# typescript configuration in a webgl project. Unexpected token : when decalring a type in typescript lint error

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to adapt typescript in a webgl javascript project. For this I tried to build a typescript configured project from scratch, and imitate packages and .eslintrc.js. When you run eslint --init, you are asked for all the options of your project and if you are using typescript, and I run that and es-lint behaves as expected with javascript and typescript. 
These are my package.json and eslintrc.js of the working typescript project from scratch.

Package.json:

```
{
"name": "typescripttrial2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "typescripttrial2",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "unknown"
  },
  "author": "LM",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.21.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.9.5"
  }
}
```

.eslinrec.js:
.eslinrec.js:

```
    module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2020: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'airbnb-base',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 11,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: [
    '@typescript-eslint',
  ],
  rules: {
    'linebreak-style': ['error', 'windows'],
  },
};
```

Now I will post my app .eslintrc.js and package.json, with my modifications indicated.

package.json:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    jquery: true
  },
  extends: [
    'airbnb/base',
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser', // <----I ADDED THIS AS IN THE WORKING PROJECT 
    (before 'babel-eslint')
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      alias: {
        map: [
          ['@', path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
        ],
        extensions: [
          '.js', '.js', '.json',
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [  <----I ADDED THIS AS IN THE WORKING PROJECT (this was added, this just was not before)
        '@typescript-eslint',
  ],
  rules: {
    'comma-dangle': ['error', {
      'arrays': 'always-multiline',
      'objects': 'always-multiline',
      'imports': 'always-multiline',
      'exports': 'always-multiline',
      'functions': 'never'
    }],
    'function-paren-newline': ['error', 'consistent'],
    'no-alert': 0,
    'no-bitwise': 0,
    'no-console': 0,
    'no-param-reassign': 0,
    'no-shadow': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/label-has-for': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/no-autofocus': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions': 0,
    'linebreak-style': [0, "windows"],
    'camelcase' : 0,
    'no-plusplus' : 0,
    'no-underscore-dangle' : 0,
    'no-buffer-constructor:': 0
  },
};
```

and the .eslintrc.js:

```
{
  "name": "webgl2-boilerplate",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf editor/node_modules",
    "lint": "eslint --cache --ext .js src",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.2.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.0.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.21.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "raw-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.36.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2"
  }
}
```

I put in comments the 2 site where I changed my project with "<----I ADDED THIS AS IN THE WORKING PROJECT" with my trials to achieve typescript linting correct behaviour in my project. The problem is that I keep finding the unexpected token error when I declare a type, and cannot figure out why. I did once again the eslint --init, downloaded all the typescript packages, and added the parser and the plugins to my .eslintrc.js, so I don't know what i'm missing.

[image]

Hope the large config files are no too overwelming. Any help is much appreciatted, before I might just traspass all the code of my project, to a new one, where typescript is working as expected. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding  `"extends": ["plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"]` in your  .eslintrc.js  file

Comment: you rule man. If you post that as an answer I will accept it. I added both: extends: [
    'airbnb/base',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
  ], because I did not mention but the purpose of all this is that I want to preserve the airbnb config. Now I need to figure out to pass all my files to TS and provide the compiled file entrypoint to the app. Thanks a lot @tHeSiD

Comment: Sure! let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  extends: [
    'airbnb/base',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'
  ],
```

Add this `'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'` to extends so that eslint  knows what exact rules regarding typescript it should use.

Node: Reminder, the order of the extends array is important as the next one  will extend or overwrite the previous ones. Ref: [ESLint - Extending Configuration Files](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#extending-configuration-files)

Comment: this one might be for you bro ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62418487/typescript-compiled-js-files-eslint-configuration